# Python APScheduler how to disable logging

Tags: python, apscheduler

I set up APScheduler to run every second via cron schedule (kind of needed/wanted).  Right now I have logger sending everything to console.

If it wasn't for logging is greatly important to what I'm working on, it'd be okay.  But, I need logging.  What I don't want is APScheduler's info logging.  Stuff like this:

```
INFO     at 2013-05-26 13:05:06,007 : Job "loadavg.run (trigger: cron[year='*', month='*', day='*', week='*', day_of_week='*', hour='*', minute='*', second='*'], next run at: 2013-05-26 13:05:06)" executed successfully
INFO     at 2013-05-26 13:05:06,008 : Running job "cpu.run (trigger: cron[year='*', month='*', day='*', week='*', day_of_week='*', hour='*', minute='*', second='*'], next run at: 2013-05-26 13:05:07)" (scheduled at 2013-05-26 13:05:06)
```

I have this in my code after I add the cron jobs:

```
logging.getLogger("apscheduler.scheduler").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

There's not any, as far as I know, configuration options for APScheduler to specify logging information, either.

I know I can specify the level of the logger to ERROR or something, but when it gets set to INFO I don't want all of this (what seems to be useless) information logged as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will first assume that you are using APScheduler for **cron-like** behavior because if you were really running via `cron(8)` every second, it would

1. Be self-defeating because [APScheduler claims](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/index.html#introduction) it's a "far better alternative to externally run cron scripts…"
2. Probably thrash the system something awful

That stipulated, the beauty of the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) is that it allows your application to have broad control over a library's logging behavior without touching its code. Unfortunately, it makes `logging` a little hard to understand at first.

Since the `INFO` level reports stuff that you aren't interested in you can:

```
class NoRunningFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.msg.startswith('Running job')

my_filter = NoRunningFilter()
logging.getLogger("apscheduler.scheduler").addFilter(my_filter)
```

These can all be specified dynamically with a [logging configuration file](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) but that's a little more magic than I've ever gotten into.

Comment: Yes, I am using APS as a cron-like scheduler.  Thanks for the filter code, I had to modify it slightly (<pre>return</pre> instead of <pre>return not record.msg.startswith('Running job')</pre>) to not spit out anything, but it works good enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: Using `return` is correct by accident because it returns `None` which happens to be false-ish in Python. Better and more explicit would be `return False`. See [PEP-20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) for further enlightenment.

Answer (score 17):

You can try this code:

```
logging.getLogger('apscheduler.executors.default').propagate = False
```

Comment: DEBUG messages will be printed anyway, so it is necessary to set the logger level to INFO.

Answer (score 14):

Here's my code, which works without complaining about missing handlers:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(every_minute, trigger='cron', second=0, id='every_minute')
logging.getLogger('apscheduler.executors.default').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

It does not disable scheduler logging completely, but it does remove the info messages the OP wanted to be rid of.

Comment: In my case, I used `logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.WARNING)`. I was getting errors when using `'apscheduler.executors.default'`. Otherwise, this was the best solution in that I still get warn/error messages, but none of the info messages that clog up my application's logs.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the logging level to error and problem solved!

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own logger and pass it as a parameter:

```
apscheduler_logger = logging.getLogger("apscheduler.scheduler")
apscheduler_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
sched = BlockingScheduler(option={'logger': apscheduler_logger})
```